# Unable to mount DVD - unable to read superblock

Tags: ubuntu, mount, dvd, io

I bought a Documentary DVD online, but when I inserted the DVD into a Windows machine, nothing happened. So, I tried with Ubuntu, and same thing happened.

When I checked dmesg after I inserted the DVD, I got this

```
[May11 20:32] ata6.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x6 frozen
[  +0.000034] ata6.00: cmd a0/00:00:00:02:00/00:00:00:00:00/a0 tag 24 pio 16388 in
                       Xpwrite, Read disk info 51 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 00res 40/00:03:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/a0 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
[  +0.000008] ata6.00: status: { DRDY }
[  +0.000010] ata6: hard resetting link
[  +0.315520] ata6: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 300)
[  +0.009245] ata6.00: configured for UDMA/133
[  +0.002180] ata6: EH complete
```

When I tried to mount using the mount command `sudo mount /dev/sr0 /mnt/cdrom`, I got

```
mount: /mnt/cdrom: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sr0,    missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

I opened up vlc on terminal and tried to open the disc (Media->Open Disc) as DVD and play. But I got this error in the vlc logs:

```
libdvdnav: Using dvdnav version 6.0.0
libdvdread: Can't seek to block 256
libdvdread:DVDOpenFileUDF:UDFFindFile /VIDEO_TS/VIDEO_TS.IFO failed
libdvdread: Can't seek to block 256
libdvdread:DVDOpenFileUDF:UDFFindFile /VIDEO_TS/VIDEO_TS.BUP failed
libdvdread: Can't open file VIDEO_TS.IFO.
libdvdnav: vm: failed to read VIDEO_TS.IFO
libdvdread: Can't seek to block 256
libdvdread:DVDOpenFileUDF:UDFFindFile /VIDEO_TS/VIDEO_TS.IFO failed
libdvdread: Can't seek to block 256
libdvdread:DVDOpenFileUDF:UDFFindFile /VIDEO_TS/VIDEO_TS.BUP failed
libdvdread: Can't open file VIDEO_TS.BUP.
libdvdread: Can't seek to block 256
libdvdread: Can't seek to block 16
libdvdread: DVDISOVolumeInfo, failed to read ISO9660 Primary Volume Descriptor!
```

I ran mount command again with -t iso9660 option, but got this message on dmesg:

```
[ +19.935654] sr 5:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#24 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[  +0.000009] sr 5:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#24 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
[  +0.000007] sr 5:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#24 Add. Sense: Unable to recover table-of-contents
[  +0.000008] sr 5:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#24 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 10 00 00 01 00
[  +0.000004] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 64
[  +0.000089] isofs_fill_super: bread failed, dev=sr0, iso_blknum=16, block=16
```

So, does this mean the DVD itself is defective or should I try something else?

Comment: Does it work in a normal DVD player?

Comment: I don't have a normal DVD player, (I can check it though, My friend has one). Can it work in normal DVD player and not in my laptop's DVD player? Are some DVD meant to play only on normal DVD players?

Comment: The DVD contents are probably scrambled, and it is additionally possible that the DVD is locked to another region.  Does the [RestrictedFormats/PlayingDVDs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats/PlayingDVDs) article help?

Comment: @Deltik Yes, I tried that, but it didn't work. In Windows, sometimes (after loading for a long time) it says, How do you want to use this disc, and gives me two options, like a USB flash drive or with CD/DVD player(the latter is greyed out), when I choose the former, it says, The disk is write protected.

Comment: Again, try it in a normal DVD player.